# Why won't write method work in hidapi package?

Tags: python-3.x, hid

I've installed the package [`hidapi`](https://pypi.org/project/hidapi/) to send steering wheel input to my race game through my joystick (if you have another better package, let me know please). The `hid` works very well for reading, as you can see below:

```
import hid

gamepad = hid.device()
gamepad.open(0x045e, 0x028e)

for i in range(100):
    print(gamepad.read(64))

# Output:
# [255, 128, 0, 128, 255, 128, 0, 128, 0, 128, 0, 64, 208, 132]
# [255, 128, 0, 128, 255, 210, 0, 128, 0, 128, 0, 64, 208, 132]
# [255, 128, 0, 128, 0, 255, 0, 128, 0, 128, 0, 64, 208, 132]
# ...
```

But, when I try to use the `write` method to set the axis (index 5), nothing happens.

```
# Trying to set axis to right. Note: element in index 4 is zero because
# for some reason, when index 5 (axis) is 255, index 4 is zero on reading. 
# And when index 5 is not 255, index 4 is 255.
while True:
    gamepad.write([255, 128, 0, 128, 0, 255, 0, 128, 0, 128, 0, 64, 208, 132])
    # I don't know if it's important, but the function returns -1 always.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An input device usually only does input, not output. What do you expect writing to an input device to actually *mean*? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I built a steering wheel detection using OpenCV, like a kinect, and I would like to use the information to move the steering wheel of the car in race games.

Comment: In some games like minecraft, I can move the camera and other things through mouse cursor. Then I can use some simple libray for moving cursor such as `pyautogui`.

Comment: But all my race games don't accept mouse input to move the steering wheel. Only joystick or a steering wheel device.

Comment: So, I was looking for some library to move the steering wheel, emulating a steering wheel driver or something like this, but I didn't find anything. I just found this solution that is using `hidapi` library having already a joystick. So, I expect moving the steering wheel of the game by writting using `hidapi`.

Comment: If you want to change the input a game receives, you likely have to put your program *between* the input device and the game. An input device usually produces a constant stream of positions *based on its hardware state*; writing to the input device will at most change the most recent position reading before the next hardware reading resets that. You might have some luck using your program to create a virtual input device, but that will likely depend strongly on the concrete usecase.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi So is there another way to send steering wheel inputs to the game? Because I really don't know how to make a middleware between my joystick and the game.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002, If your game accepts joystick as input there is https://pypi.org/project/vgamepad/ library that provides the ability to manipulate virtual joystick through python. However, you would still need to somehow come up with a conversion between hidapi and vgamepad structures.